# Using scrapy in a script and passing args

Tags: scrapy

I want to use scrapy in a larger project, but I am unsure how to pass args like name,start_urls,and allowed_domains. As I understand it name,start_urls,and allowed_domains variables are settings for process.crawl, but I am not able to use self.var like I have with line- `site = self.site` since self obviously isn't defined there. There is also the problem of the proper way to return. At the end of the day I just want a way to crawl all urls on a single domain from within a script.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
#from project.spiders.test_spider import SpiderName
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

crawledUrls = []
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spider_example_name'
    
    def __init__(self,site):
        self.site=site
    
    site = self.site
    domain = urlparse(site).netloc
    start_urls = [site]
    allowed_domains = [domain]
    
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #I think there is a way to do this with yeild
        print(self.site)
        crawledUrls.append(response.url)

def main():
    spider = MySpider('http://quotes.toscrape.com')
    process.crawl(spider)
    process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
    print("###########################################")
    print(len(crawledUrls))
    print(crawledUrls)
    print("###########################################")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

See this comment on the scrapy github:
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1823#issuecomment-189731464

It appears you made the same mistakes as the reporter in that comment, where

1. `process.crawl(...)` takes a class, not instance, of Spider
2. params can be specified within the call to `process.crawl(...)` as keyword arguments. Check the possible kwargs in [the Scrapy docs for CrawlerProcess](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html?highlight=CrawlerProcess#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess).

So, for example, your main could look like this:

```
def main():
    process.crawl(
        MySpider,
        start_urls=[
            "http://example.com", 
            "http://example.org"
    )
    process.start()
    ...
```